# scons executable + shared library in project directory

Tags: c, linux, scons

Here's a sample SConscript file:

```
env = Environment()
hello_lib = env.SharedLibrary('hello', ['libhello.c'])
exe = env.Program('main', ['main.c'], LIBS=hello_lib)

env.Install('/usr/lib', hello_lib)
env.Install('/usr/bin', exe)
env.Alias('install', '/usr/bin')
env.Alias('install', '/usr/lib')
```

It builds one shared library, and one executable linked to that library:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o libhello.os -c -fPIC libhello.c
gcc -o libhello.so -shared libhello.os
gcc -o main.o -c main.c
gcc -o main main.o libhello.so
scons: done building targets.
```

Now, the issue is the created executable will not find the shared library when running it from the project directory, 
which is quite natural, since neither the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable is set, or 
any RPATH is set in the executable:

```
[fedora 00:07:10 2 ~] $ ./main 
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libhello.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can always set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable while developing, but this becomes cumbersome if the project has a directory hierarchy with several shared libraries in sub_directories.

The GNU autotools/libtool solves this by automagically set the RPATH of the executable to wherever the shared libraries are built in the project directory, which allows for easy running/testing the executable while developing. And it relinks the executable when installing it to leave out those RPATH which arn't needed anymore.

Is there anything similar to what autotools does that  can be done with scons to ease testing the executables while developing ?

Is there any recommended way to build applications using shared libraries with scons, that makes it easy to run the executable from the build directory ?

Answer (score 3):

You could modify each of the SConscript files which produce libraries, like so:

```
hello_lib = env.SharedLibrary('#/lib/hello', ['libhello.c'])
```

All of your shared libraries are now located in a single directory.

The SConscript which produces an executable becomes:

```
exe = env.Program('main', ['main.c'], LIBPATH='#/lib', LIBS=hello_lib)
```

Then you will be able to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to `$PWD/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for the [`RPATH`](http://www.scons.org/wiki/UsingOrigin) option in scons.

From the wiki page, the RPATH is described as scons as the following.

> A list of paths to search for shared libraries when running programs.
>   Currently only used in the GNU linker (gnulink) and IRIX linker
>   (sgilink). Ignored on platforms and toolchains that don't support it.
>   Note that the paths added to RPATH are not transformed by scons in any
>   way: if you want an absolute path, you must make it absolute yourself.

Comment: Yes, and I'm looking for advice on how to best do this with SCons, in a similar way that automake/libtool handles it. Or are you saying I must manually fiddle with setting the RPATH for each potential shared library within a project, and somehow make sure the RPATH is unset when the install target is running ?

Comment: @user964970, `RPATH` is generally used for shared libraries that are bundled with the application, and the wiki explains how to specify a **relative path** inside `RPATH` so that the built application should work both in the development environment and in the target environment.

Comment: @user964970, Of course, this requires that the relative directory structure in your development environment's build output matches the relative directory structure of deployment, but I think that is a reasonable requirement.

Comment: Well, that's quite an unreasonable requirment to me. e.g I have 2 shared libraries under the libA and libB source folders, which would require me to set the RPATH to libA and libB, whilst installing project, libraries goes in /usr/lib (and no RPATH is needed).

Comment: @user964970, I am certainly not asking you to change your source directory structure, only that your *binary* distribution structure should match that of the deployment. When you build your `libA` and `libB`, put the *output* in a local directory called `lib`.

Comment: Any hint on how to do that with scons except for manually copying the files ? The variant_dir will not help much as it also places intermediate files in the variant dir (which ofcourse might clash with filenames).